# Application Development With Old facebook APIs

Tags: facebook

I want to develop facebook applications and I have bought some books from amazon. But this books contents are for old facebook APIs. (2008-2009).
Can I develop applications with old api? Or I have to use new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the old api's, but as you can probably imagine it is discouraged. Read more in the [facebook developer documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/).

**EDIT**
Given your name, I assume that you know a bit of php. To get started just go to http://www.facebook.com/developers and create a new application. Facebook then presents you with the following tutorial, that I think you should be able to follow:

> Step 1: Download Facebook's PHP Library
>
> Extract this archive into a directory on your hosting server where you can host and run PHP code:

```
$ curl -L http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tarball/master | tar xvz
$ mv facebook-php-sdk-* facebook-php-sdk
$ cp facebook-php-sdk/examples/example.php index.php
```

> Step 2: Replace the IDs in index.php to have your own app information
>
> It should look like this when you're done:

```
<?php
// Awesome Facebook Application
// 
// Name: YourAppName
// 

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'CHANGE_TO_YOUR_OWN_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'CHANGE_TO_YOUR_OWN_SECRET',
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

Comment: I need practical tutorials. 2+2 = 4 documantation is not very useful for a newbie like me :(

Comment: @phpExe, sorry to break the news to you, but if you can't read the documentation for an API and get something meaningful out of it, then maybe a facebook app is a bit too ambitious a project.

Comment: @phpExe, I have updated my answer with a short tutorial that you should try following, as found on facebook.

Comment: Thanks alot for answer. I have created some applications but Im wondering about books and documentation. The api is changed but the rich platform like facebook has not any new book for new api =)

Comment: @phpExe You don't need a book. Everything you need to know is documented online. If you are in doubt about any details I'm sure that you'll find answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not start a new app with the old APIs. Facebook has deprecated many of the old APIs and is in the process of deprecating the rest of them. Additionally, the authentication system changed completely about 6 months ago. Sorry for the bad news but books on Facebook that are more than about 3-6 months old are basically worthless at this point.

Comment: There is no any new book. There is not new tutorial on internet. Facebook documentation is not usefull for me. Could you please suggest a book for such applications? Thanks in advance

Comment: @phpExe Welcome to life as a Facebook developer. Don't go near any sharp objects or cliffs.